# Position an UIView between two views in the center?

Tags: ios, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I want to position `UIView` relative to the before and after positioned views, i.e. their enters distance should be equal. So x, o, y, are views.

`x <----> o <----> y`

distance(d, o) = distance(o, y)

Is it possible in storyboard?
I do not want to center it relative to the container.

Comment: If you are just trying to center it within its container, you can use a center horizontal constraint. Is that what you are looking to do?

Comment: no, I would avoid it

Comment: Look into equal width constraints. You might be able to set up leading and trailing constraints and require them to be equal widths, which would effectively center the view between the other two views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put two extra invisible views between `x,o` and `o,y`, and set **equal width constraints** for them.

I have now this layout: `x-v1-o-v2-y`

Comment: Such a simple solution! Why didn't I think of that? (Still worked for me in 2022!)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a container, with three subviews, a, b and c, and you want to space them equally:

```
 ___________________
|                   |
|  ___   ___   ___  |
| |_a_| |_b_| |_c_| |
|                   |
|___________________|
```

You can try the following constraints if you don't want to have spacer views (what follows is not code):

`b.centerX = container.centerX`

`a.centerX = container.centerX * 0.5`

`c.centerX = container.centerX * 1.5`

I think you'll have to center all the views first and then edit the multiplier parameter of the created constraint.